# Is the "clean" design from many websites the same?

Tags: website-design

On many websites selling (or offering) a software, there is an almost constant desygn style. I think of (among many others) atom.io, angularjs.org, nodejs.org, typescriptlang.org, v-play.net, qt.io and code.visualstudio.com.

They all have a header which is always on top of the screen, a black footer, and white body and often paragrpahs with a picture alternating left floating and right floating.

Is it only the 2010's fashion, or are all of these powered by a specific CMS/framework/something ?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that #1 it's trendy right now but above all #2 the layout works well for delivering this type of content. As a bonus, #3 a consistent layout across the similar content makes it even more user-friendly as the users are already familiar with it and don't need to learn anything new to use it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A lot of these sites use responsive WordPress themes, free or purchased, that let you quickly have a presence with content and functionality.  If you look at the site's code or run a [check for specific software used to build the site](https://www.oss-usa.com/framework-version-test), you're very likely to see WordPress or another framework.

Comment: There are all sorts of tools to create sites like these, including a plain text editor

Comment: I agree with @ZachSaucier; of the examples given in the question, only two of seven use WordPress. Both use it for content management and have original styles. I believe this design is so prevalent because it works well, not because it's easy to deploy (they're software developers; chances are, someone knows how to use HTML and CSS). Each site shows the purpose of the software in a visually-appealing manner and directs users through the process of installing it. This seems like a case of confirmation bias, as it's not difficult to find counterexamples with vastly different designs.

Comment: A lot of companies don't "just use wordpress themes", for example the majority of the sites referenced in the original question. Software sites, like these, follow that structure because it is familiar and it clearly shows the features etc. It is a pattern that works well, so why change something if it isn't broken? :)